# Ansible: How to override default forks value with value larger than 5 from code or inventory?

Tags: ansible

I need every task in my playbook to run on 10 hosts simultaneously, is it possible to override default forks value (5) with value larger than 5 by setting a variable in the playbook code or inventory? Cannot use `ansible.cfg` file or command line.
Tried to set `forks` and `ansible_forks` in inventory variables, environment variable `ANSIBLE_FORKS` in playbook -- nothing seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

No. It's not possible to set [*DEFAULT_FORKS*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-forks) in a play or inventory.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the first given answer it is not possible to configure the

> *Maximum number of forks Ansible will use to execute tasks on target hosts.*

after Ansible has started to run. This is because with the [Ansible Configuration Settings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-configuration-settings) you configure how the execution environment was started and is hold in memory. This can't then be overwritten during runtime.

So

> *Cannot use `ansible.cfg` file or command line ... environment variable `ANSIBLE_FORKS` ...*

you will need to.